# changing box attributes onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript-objects

trying to create this file that changes an object's attributes (size, color, fade out, and reset) with the click of buttons. Not working right now and trying to figure out what I'm missing .... Any thoughts?

[changing a box size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcr5Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is the duplication of attribute in your `<script>` tag and actual javascript in between the `<script>` and `</script>`. That's poor coding.
If you need code referenced in the file named 'javascript.js', then it needs to be it's own `<script>` declaration in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

and THAT'S IT. THEN follow with any code you want on the page with a new `<script>` declaration block.
IF you're trying to make the jQuery library available, that can be accomplished with this: (put it in the `<head></head>` section of your html code.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery is very particular about the selectors you feed it:

1) no prefix symbol means an html tag: `$("table")` means match any `<table>` in the HTML

2) a dot prefix symbol means match a class: `$(".button1")` WILL FIND the elements that you actually have in your code. They are not being found because you didn't prefix with a dot in your selector.

3) a hashtag/pound-sign/number-sign means match an ID: `$("#box")` will find that box at the beginning of your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        $("#box").css({'height':400,'width':400});
    });
    $(".button2").click(function(){
        $("#box").css('background-color','blue');
    });
    $(".button3").click(function() {
       $("#box").fadeOut();
    });
    $(".button4").click(function() {
       $("#box").show().css({'height':150, 'width':150, 'background-color':'orange'});
    });
});
</script>
```

here's a link to a [FUNCTIONING codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWzajO) showing that what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: If there's something I missed in your question that my response does not cover, please let me know so I can offer a better or more complete response to your question.
Thank you.